# Removing current image before loading a new one JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I load an image from URL by using document.createElement('img'). And a button triggers it. But, every time I click the button, it creates another img element instead of removing the current one. Can you help me to remove the current image so that there is always maximum one image displayed. Here is the code:

```html
<script>
    function() {
        var imageUrl = document.getElementById('image-url').value;
        var loadedImage = document.createElement('img');
        loadedImage.src = imageUrl;
        loadedImage.className = 'container';
        document.getElementById('imagePlace').appendChild(loadedImage);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't *append* it, *replace its src attribute*. Also for future posts it would be better when you post your code here as text instead of using a picture

Comment: You can use JSfiddle to post your code. Instead of image

Comment: Try to replace the current image. document.getElementById("image-url").src="image-path";

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/appendChild) method, you add a node to your document, so some changes to your code are required - you should check if the image node is already present and either create a new `img` element or replace the `src` attribute of the existing one.

```html
<script>
    function() {
        // Get a new image url
        var imageUrl = document.getElementById('image-url').value;

        // Get a parent element
        var parent = document.getElementById('imagePlace');
        
        // Try to get an 'img' element that is inside '#imagePlace' node.
        var currentImage = parent.querySelector('img');
        
        // Check if there already is an image in the document.
        if (currentImage) {
            // If there is, replace its 'src' attribute with the new url.
            currentImage.src = imageUrl;
        }
        else {
            // If there is no image in the parent, create and add new image node.
            var loadedImage = document.createElement('img');
            loadedImage.src = imageUrl;
            loadedImage.className = 'container';
            parent.appendChild(loadedImage);
        }        
    }
</script>
```

In other approach you may start with removing the `img` node if it's present in the `#imagePlace` container, however changing the `src` attribute is "cheaper" to perform.

```html
<script>
    function() {
        // Get a new image url
        var imageUrl = document.getElementById('image-url').value;

        // Get a parent element
        var parent = document.getElementById('imagePlace');
        
        // Try to get an 'img' element that is inside '#imagePlace' node.
        var currentImage = parent.querySelector('img');
        
        // Check if there already is an image in the document.
        if (currentImage) {
            // If it's there, remove it.
            currentImage.remove();
        }
        
        // Create and add new image node.
        var loadedImage = document.createElement('img');
        loadedImage.src = imageUrl;
        loadedImage.className = 'container';
        parent.appendChild(loadedImage);
                
    }
</script>
```